# Crystal report issue in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

Whenever i run multiple reports at the same time, i get this exception. I set to Report document to support unlimited number of crystal reports.

object Report;

Report is created with an instance of cyrstal report and

in page unload report is set to null. However i don't know how to dispose an object? (probably disposing will help). Please share how to dispose an object.

Any thoughts on this?

> System.Exception: Load report failed. --->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The maximum report
>   processing jobs limit configured by your system administrator has been
>   reached. at
>   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.ReportClientDocumentClass.Open(Object&
>   DocumentPath, Int32 Options) at
>   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.Open(Object&
>   DocumentPath, Int32 Options) at
>   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened()
>   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String
>   filename, OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob) at
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String
>   filename)

Comment: Perhaps post some code showing the use of the object, in brief...

Comment: Here's a solution http://forums.asp.net/t/985049.aspx/1

Comment: Thanks Mathieu, close and dispose cleared my issue.

Comment: @Sharpeye500 See my explaination, post some code if you want me to verify your report binding scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your code I can't say for sure whether you are disposing the report object correctly or not.  There is a memory leak that can occur when the report is bound to the viewer in cases where the viewer is disposed leaving the report object dereferrenced and never gets disposed.  This causes the 'PrintJobCount' to increment until it reaches it's limit and crashes.  You can cautiously change the registry value under 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Business Objects[your version #]\Report Application Server\Server\PrintJobLimit' but this will just give you more room until you recycle your app pool.  In the long term you should determine if it's a memory leak before making any registry changes to your production environment.